# prove that generalized completeness implies compactness

Tags: logic

prove that generalized completeness implies compactness

I suppose that all of $Z'_{s}$ finite subsets are consistent. If Z itself is finite, then, because any set counts as one of its own subsets, Z is consistent. If Z is infinite, we can order its sentences in some definite order I have this but I do not know if I am correct.

if you can give me an idea of how to approach it, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

The key here is that by completeness, for a set of sentences $\Gamma$, if $\Gamma \vDash \bot$ then $\Gamma \vdash \bot$. So, instead of trying to prove it for the finite case and then for the infinite case, try to prove it more generally by the fact that {$\bot$} is finite and unsatisfiable.

For the converse, note that if $\Gamma$ is satisfiable, then every formula $\varphi \in \Gamma$ is satisfiable and that a finite set of sentences is satisfiable if and only if all of its members are satisfiable. That should be enough to complete the proof.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand why using $\bot$ helps to prove that completeness implies  compactness

Comment: If $\Gamma \not \vdash \bot$, then there is a model $\mathcal M$ that satisfies $\Gamma$.